# Strange battery graph

Tags: battery, battery-life

A friend's Motorola Moto G (titan) on Android 5.0.2 (Stock) shows this really weird battery graph. Does anyone know what's going on here or how to fix it?
[image: Moto G buggy battery graph]

Comment: Further explain what his configuration was. What apps does he have installed? Does he charge/swap batteries often? Is he rooted?

Comment: Stock, unrooted, battery not swappable, normal charge/discharge cycle

Comment: No special apps, just Gapps, Motorola defaults and a few standard apps (WhatsApp, K-9 Mail, ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since he is stock, unrooted, and non-swappable battery, he may have a faulty battery!

Every battery has a built-in circuit that reports its charge, temperature, and stability. That's why every smartphone battery has 3 or 4 prongs (contact points), rather than just the 2 for positive and negative. **Best case scenario** his percentage is just reporting incorrectly, **worst case** he may have an unstable cell that could combust. I would recommend looking up disassembly videos for the phone, and replacing the internal battery if it is accessible.